# dynamically casting in SQL server functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to do create a function which would basically take float or integer values and convert to decimal of particular length and precision.

I have written the code below, but it seems `CAST` does not allow variable withing `DECIMAL` function :

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DECI(@in as sql_variant,@len as int, @prec as int)
returns sql_variant
as
begin
     return CAST(@in as decimal(@len,@prec))
end
```

Comment: Simply put you can't do this, not in a function anyway. You *could* in a SP, using dynamic SQL, however, I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: This can't be done in a function. You can't parameterize these properties of the decimal data type (as you've learned the hard way), so the only thing to do something that *might* work is to use dynamic SQL - but that can't be used in a function - it can only be used in a stored procedure.

Comment: The problem is that a function needs to return a known type, so the engine can correctly use the return meta-data to do checks and validations. This means that the scale and precision of the decimal (in this case) must be fixed. In an SP, you can response with a `SELECT` of multiple rows and columns, even if they vary over time or by the execution parameters.

Comment: It is technically possible to do this -- simply have a case statement enumerating every possible combination of length and precision. But it should be immediately obvious why this is not an attractive approach... and even when you've achieved "success" this way, you're still left with an `SQL_VARIANT` that you normally can't do anything with without explicit conversion, so you've gained nothing.

Comment: *"The problem is that the function needs to return a known type"* *technically* `sql_variant` is a "known" type, @EzLo, but using that data type has it own set of... Shall we say "features" related to it.

Comment: There are programs that have the function DEC(@var,@length,@Precision) used in them. What DEC() function does is that it takes 3 parameters like the function and converts it into a decimal value . This can be achieved by replacing the DEC() calls with CAST(@var as decimal(@length,@precision)) in the select statements.  But, that would mean changing a lot of code manually

Comment: SQL isn't a programming language, @sushovanDutta, don't treat it like one.

Comment: i dont want to touch the SQl thats why i am writing the function to work like the function CAST and convert the incoming data in to proper Decimal types as its is done in CAST@Larnu

Comment: *"i dont want to touch the SQl"* Then why are you trying to `CREATE` a function?

Comment: @sushovanDutta: Do touch the SQL statement. You'll achieve much better results and much more maintainable code in the long run. Saving time with something like this will come back later on in the project and you will spend way more time to clean this up, than what you save now.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit casting from `SQL_VARIANT` to most types (including `DECIMAL`) is not allowed, so you'll have to do explicit ones in most queries anyways

When you try to use this in (for example) in an `INSERT` statement

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
    DecimalCol DECIMAL(3,2)
);

INSERT INTO @TestTable
(
    DecimalCol
)
VALUES
    (dbo.DECI(1.1, 3, 2))
```

You will face with the following error message:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 44
>   Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to decimal is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Now, you'll have to update your query to:

```
INSERT INTO @TestTable
(
    DecimalCol
)
VALUES
    (CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), dbo.DECI(1.1, 3, 2)))
```

At this point, you did nothing, but a performance killer.

Do your stuff in the query directly:

```
INSERT INTO @TestTable
(
    DecimalCol
)
VALUES
    (CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), 1.1))
```

Comment: This function has performance implications that are probably even more horrid than your average scalar-valued function, as bad as those already are, as this produces an enormous execution plan. (I haven't verified if SQL Server will even want to compile it, as the whole exercise seems pointless, but that's another concern.) That could be "fixed" by breaking the statement up, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is pointless, I totally agree. There are much more problems with this code, than it solves, this is why I have the bold statement at the beginning.

Comment: Well, if you think the code is useless, why post in in the first place? even more so when that option have already been written and explained why it's bad in the comments to the question - so why bother posting it as an answer?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: First, that to show that it can indeed be done in this specific case. Then second, to point out how bad idea it is to do so.

Comment: IMHO, the last part of your answer is the only part that's worth keeping - showing why the OP had a bad / impractical / impossible idea is a good answer. Showing how to implement that bad / impractical idea is not - but then again, that's just my opinion - you don't have to agree with it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I might restructure it in the future, both of you have some valid points.